# ml5.js: including rnn into website; generating doesnt work

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to implement my simple RNN into my website. Tensorflowjs doesn't work for "some" reason (I spent like a week on debugging errors, which then caused another one), so I decided to use ml5.js. I was able to load my model, but then I got an error: "Error: manifest.json not found at model/trump.model/. [object ProgressEvent]" ("model/trump.model" is the path to my model)

I just adapted the code from their documentation (https://ml5js.org/docs/CharRNN), didn't work, so I looked my error up, but didn't get any results in accordance with my problem.

Just some basic code, maybe not the best but i don't care right now

- JUST SOME ORDINARY HTML AND CSS CODE *

  $("#generate-btn").on("click", function(){
      model = ml5.charRNN("model/trump.model", modelLoaded)

  ```
  function modelLoaded() {
    console.log("Model loaded! :)")
  }

  text = "...Thank you so much.  That's so nice.  Isn't he a great guy.  He doesn't get a fair press; he doesn't get it.  It's just not fair.  And I have to tell you I'm here, and very strongly here, because I have great respect f".substring(0, 40) // WAS TO LAZY TO COUNT THE CHARACTERS

  generated = ""
  model.generate({seed:text, length=100}, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)
    generated = result
  })

  $("#output").html(generated)
  ```

  })

https://ibb.co/5W67Pjq that's the website + error message

expected: under the h1 headline is supposed to be the generated text

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you (worked for me).  I am running IIS Web Server and it does not recognize filese without an extenstion.  I added the following to the web.config for an asp.net web app and it worked...

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/xml" />
    </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```